# Lua memcached binary protocol

Tags: binary, lua, memcached

I'm looking lua memcached client that supports memcached binary protocol.

Could you recommend something?

Comment: Nope, plenty of Redis bindings, none for memcached. If you'll end up writing one (try Redis first if you're considering alternatives), please share it to the community.

Comment: Ah, but maybe I'm wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a client that supports memcached binary protocol.

[lua-resty-couchbase](https://github.com/iqiyi/lua-resty-couchbase) - Lua couchbase client driver for the ngx_lua based on the cosocket API.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about *binary* protocol, but check this out: https://github.com/silentbicycle/lua-memcached

Also, this one may serve as a reference (it is for ngx_lua, so it is unlikely that you'll be able to immediately reuse it out of the box): https://github.com/agentzh/lua-resty-memcached

I did not try either of the modules, please do leave feedback here in comments if you will try them.

Comment: Cool! Please post a link here as an answer :-)

Comment: Lua-memcached does't support binary protocol. I've already implemented lua binary client myself, and I'm planning to share it at guthub.

Answer (score 0):

I've publish lua binary client:

http://github.com/kolchanov/Lua-couchbase